# Incorrect formula?

Tags: c, math, pi

So here is a program that is supposed to calculate an approximation to the value of pi if you take enough terms into the sum which is mathematically described in the following program and calculates the expression of the root, you get a value that gets closer and closer to the value of pi the more terms you have.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
    int j, terms;
    double sum, precision, pi;
    printf("How many terms: "); scanf("%d", &terms);
    for(j=1;j<=terms;j++)
        sum+=1/(j*j);
    pi = sqrt(6*sum);
    printf("Pi: %lf.\n", pi);
}
```

But there is something making it go wrong here and I can't quite figure out what.

```
sum+=1/(j*j);
```

I thought the mistake might be in that line because all others look fine,thinking at first maybe the computer isn't counting decimals.I'm unsure.But my question is: What is it in this code that makes it malfunction?And how do I fix it?

Comment: In what way is it going wrong?

Comment: You could also try the Monte Carlo method - you might get extra marks for that!

Comment: It was staying on the same value no matter how many terms you give.

Comment: @EdHeal I wouldn't bet on that.  Sounds like a gamble.

Comment: I see you are using a C89 compiler (no return type specified for `main`, compiler assumes `int`) ... oh! wait ... it's a C99 compiler after all (no `return` statement inside `main`, compiler assumes `return 0;`) ... but but ... C89 and C99 at the same time is a really strange compiler :) Suggestion: specify the return type of `main` **and** specify a `return` statement.

Comment: @Anycorn - It is a very Good method of computing PI. Pythagoras would approve!

Comment: Beware that this series converges very slowly. You'll need an unreasonable number of iterations to get a handful of correct digits.

Comment: Just for clarity, why not add an initializer to the declaration `double sum=0.0...`

Answer (score 7):

This performs integer division:

```
1/(j*j);
```

try this:

```
sum+=1.0/(j*j);
```

If `j*j` might overflow, do this

```
sum+=1.0/((double)j*j);
```